# Is there a way to convert the output of a form into an array as PHP does automatically, but using jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

Is there a way for me to convert the output of a form that uses a multidimensional array notation for its field names into an actual associative array or object of that data?

For instance, I have two fields:

```
<input type="text" name="contract[main][date]" />
<input type="text" name="contract[options][timer]" />
```

I want to prevent the default action of the form (which I know how to do) and then convert all of the inputs in the form into an object or associatve array that mimics the structure of the associative array that would be available in PHP's $_GET or $_POST variable if I were trying to do this server-side. Something like:

```
var contract = {
    main: {
        date:'input field value'
    },
    options: {
        timer:'another input field value'
    }
};
```

Comment: not really. PHP's array notation is a hack, and means nothing to JS or html. you'd have to extract all of the input fields from the DOM, parse the name attributes, and build your own arrays. json.stringify/jquery.serialize will take a form and turn it into a submittable string, but again, the PHP notation is completely opaque to them. they just see some form field names, not an array.

Comment: Not without using eval or your own custom string parsing for the name.

Comment: Jquery might help .serializeArray()
http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: Yes, but that gives you an array that looks like this `[{name:'contract[main][date]', value:'input field value'}]`

Answer (score 0):

```
function formToArray(form) {
    var formArray = new Array();
    var formElements = form.find('input[name]');

    formElements.each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var value = $(this).val();

        // replace all occurrences of ']' with ''
        name = name.split(']').join('');

        var elements = name.split('[');
        var previousRef = formArray;

        for(var i = 0, count = elements.length; i < count; i++) {
            var key = elements[i];

            if (!previousRef[key]) {
                previousRef[key] = new Array();
            }

            if (i != elements.length - 1) {
                previousRef = previousRef[key];
            } else if (i == elements.length - 1) {
                previousRef[key] = value;
            }
        }
    });

    return formArray;
}

var form = $('#my_form');
var formArray = formToArray(form);
```